# Can an event emitter replace pub/sub

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, eventemitter

I am currently using [Publisher.js](https://github.com/rpflorence/publisher.js) in an app and also [Microee](https://github.com/mixu/microee) which is a tiny EventEmitter. It seems to me that if I had a global microee instance it could be used in much the same way as pub/sub. For example in Publisher.js I can do:

```
publisher.subscribe('onAwesome', function (one, two, foo){
  console.log(one, two, foo);
});

publisher.publish('onAwesome', 1, 2, 'foo');
```

and in Microee I can do:

```
microee.on('onAwesome', function (one, two, foo){
  console.log(one, two, foo);
});

microee.emit('onAwesome', 1, 2, 'foo');
```

So I'm wondering if I'm missing something here in replacing this specific use case of pub/sub with an event emitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're actually spot on - that code can be *directly replaced* with an [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter).

Events with the EventEmitter support arguments in their event calls, along with many other features that you'd benefit from - assuming you're using Node.js.